# File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm just learning, and I tried to run this simple code :
ihave a problem , can we help me :
this is my code for my apps:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = """
MDFloatLayout:

    Carousel:



        MDFloatLayout:
            id : slide     


            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "First Name"

                size_hint_x: 0.5
                icon_right: "account"
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
                font_style: "H6"
                text_color: "Custom"
            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Last Name"
                size_hint_x: 0.5
                icon_right: "account"
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.4}

            MDRaisedButton:
                text:"NEXT"
                size_hint_x:0.2
                pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.2}
                on_release: app.next()

"""


class Jeu(FloatLayout):
    def debut(self):
        self.size = Window.size
        self.add_widget(Image(source='w2.jpg', allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False))


class ViTVApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv1 = Builder.load_string(KV)
        kv = Jeu()
        img = Image(source="1611647504798.png",
                    size_hint_y=0.15, size_hint_x=0.15, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.85}, opacity=0.8)

        kv.debut()
        kv.add_widget(img)
        kv.add_widget(kv1)
        return kv

    def next(self):
        self.root.ids.slide.ids.carousel.load_next(mode="next")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    ViTVApp().run()
```

The console repeatedly gives this error, but the window pops up just fine:

File "", line 30, in 
File "E:\Developpement\ViTV\P1\P3.py", line 64, in next
self.root.ids.slide.ids.carousel.load_next(mode="next")
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to access an `id` in a widget that has no `ids`. The root widget of your `App` is the `Jeu` object, but only widgets built using `kv` (like `kv1`) will have `ids`, so `self.root.ids` will fail. Plus, the only `id` that you have defined in your `kv` is `slide`, so any attempt to access an `id` of `carousel` will also fail.

One way to fix this is to actually define a `carousel` id in your `kv` like this:

```
KV = """
MDFloatLayout:

    Carousel:
        id: carousel  # new id

        MDFloatLayout:
        ...
        ...
```

Then, save a reference to the widget built using that `kv`, and use that reference to access the `Carousel` widget:

```
class ViTVApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.kv1 = Builder.load_string(KV)  #save reference
        kv = Jeu()
        img = Image(source="1611647504798.png",
                    size_hint_y=0.15, size_hint_x=0.15, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.85}, opacity=0.8)

        kv.debut()
        kv.add_widget(img)
        kv.add_widget(self.kv1)
        return kv

    def next(self):
        self.kv1.ids.carousel.load_next(mode="next")  # use saved reference
```